# chemformula bug with additional braces in sub- / superscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, chemformula

I get a strange bug when using additional braces in sub- or superscript inside a `\ch{}`.
The following minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\ch{Cl^{n+1}} \ch{Cl^{{n+1}}} \ch{Cl_{n+1}} \ch{Cl_{{n+1}}}
\end{document}
```

results in this output
[image]
Is there any reason / solution known?

Comment: it's not a bug i think. the package documentation clearly states that the syntax `\ch{A+B}` will yield a `A\tp B`, where `\tp` is a triple bond. (under section 6.4 Charges and superscript) so my guess is by placing `n+1` in double braces, it is being parsed as `Cl superscript {n+1}` which expands to `Cl superscript \tp`. Probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug but a maybe unexpected feature. Although I didn't explicitly plan it this way it is not unexpected to me:

The additional braces somewhat hide the input from the parser. A `+` in sub- and superscripts gets replaced by `\chemformula_plus:`. If it is inside braces the parser doesn't see it which means it doesn't get replaced. However, in a later state of the parsing all remaining `+` get replaced by `\chemformula_triple_bond:` which is what you see.

> Is there any […] solution known?

Well, yes: don't use the additional pair of braces, or remove the replacement of `+` with triple bonds completely

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\RemoveChemCompoundProperty{+}
\begin{document}

\ch{Cl^{{n+1}}} \ch{Cl_{{n+1}}}

\end{document}
```

Besides, in my opinion the correct input would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{Cl^{$n+1$}} \ch{Cl_{$n+1$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I actually used `\textcolor{blue}{$n+1$}` inside the superscript and then noticed that the outcome was not what I had expected. So I broke it down to the minimal example above.

Comment: @Hypnotoad then use `\ch{Cl^{\color{blue}$n+1$}}` :)